# SQL Query with a count condition

Tags: sql, oracle12c

**Here is my table structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE CITY(
  CITY_ID NUMBER(3) CONSTRAINT CITY_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY,
  CITY_NAME VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT CITY_NAME_NN NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE PILOT(
  PILOT_ID NUMBER(3) CONSTRAINT PILOT_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY,
  LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT LAST_NAME_NN NOT NULL,
  FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT FIRST_NAME_NN NOT NULL,
  CITY_ID NUMBER(3) CONSTRAINT CITY_ID_FK REFERENCES CITY(CITY_ID),
  SALARY NUMBER(7,2) CONSTRAINT SALARY_CK CHECK (SALARY >= 5000 AND SALARY <= 7000));

CREATE TABLE PLANE(
  PLA_ID NUMBER(2) CONSTRAINT PLANE_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY,
  PLA_DESC VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT PLANE_DESC_NN NOT NULL,
  MAX_PASSENGER NUMBER(3),
  CITY_ID NUMBER(3) CONSTRAINT PLANE_CITY_ID_FK REFERENCES CITY(CITY_ID),
  CONSTRAINT MAX_PASSENGER_CK CHECK (MAX_PASSENGER <= 500));

CREATE TABLE FLIGHT(
  FLIGHT_ID NUMBER(3) CONSTRAINT FLIGHT_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY,
  PILOT_ID NUMBER(3) CONSTRAINT FLIGHT_PILOT_ID_FK REFERENCES PILOT(PILOT_ID),
  PLA_ID NUMBER(2) CONSTRAINT FLIGHT_PLA_ID_FK REFERENCES PLANE(PLA_ID),
  CITY_DEP NUMBER(3) CONSTRAINT FLIGHT_CITY_DEP_FK REFERENCES CITY(CITY_ID),
  CITY_ARR NUMBER(3) CONSTRAINT FLIGHT_CITY_ARR_FK REFERENCES CITY(CITY_ID),
  DEP_DATE DATE,
  DEP_TIME NUMBER(4),
  ARR_TIME NUMBER(4),
  CONSTRAINT ARR_TIME_CK CHECK (ARR_TIME > DEP_TIME));
```

The question I have in this lab is to display pilots (ID and Name) who perform two or more flights out of Montreal (It is required that I use the city name in the query and not the ID)

Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
SELECT PILOT_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME
FROM PILOT
JOIN FLIGHT USING (PILOT_ID)
WHERE CITY_DEP=(SELECT CITY_ID
                FROM CITY
                WHERE CITY_NAME='MONTREAL')
```

Obviously this gets me part of the answer, but it is not displaying exactly the information I need which is simply the pilots who make this fight >= 2 times.

Comment: I don't see any column for the date.  You might want to show us the structure of all tables.

Comment: I'm going to further detail my question. First time using site, sorry for that.

Comment: Without trying it... something like this, though perhaps not terribly efficient... Flight left join City left Join Pilot where City=Montreal group by City, Pilot having count > 2

Comment: @Julien thanks for the data structure info, I edited the code below accordingly and believe that should get you where you need to be. To be able to know the amount of times per day a pilot departs, you'll need to wrap a `CASE WHEN` with your conditional (that the departure city be Montreal) into a `COUNT` to count the amount of times each pilot meets that conditional.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FETCH ROWS

```
SELECT PILOT_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME
FROM PILOT
JOIN FLIGHT USING (PILOT_ID)
WHERE CITY_DEP=(SELECT CITY_ID
                FROM CITY
                WHERE CITY_NAME='MONTREAL')
FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: I don't believe this accomplishes the goal of aggregating a non-aggregated data set. This is essentially an Oracle `limit` clause that will just pull the top two rows that meet the query conditions. 

I believe OP has a table with one row for all flights, and wants to find pilots who have at least two rows of data where `city_dep = 'MONTREAL'`.

Answer (score 0):

*Edited with new information on data structure*

#### Understanding your goal

I believe I understand your goal to be querying pilot level data for pilots who have departed from Montreal at least twice in one day.

#### Query Solution

If my assumptions are true, I believe you can meet your needs by doing something similar to this:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE flight_per_day ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS AS
SELECT
       p.pilot_id,
       f.dep_date,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN c.city_name = 'MONTREAL' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as 
        montreal_cnt
  FROM flights f
       LEFT JOIN pilot p ON p.pilot_id = f.pilot_id
       LEFT JOIN city c on f.city_dep = c.city_id
 GROUP BY 1, 2;


    SELECT
           p.pilot_id,
           p.first_name,
           p.last_name
      FROM flight_per_day fp
           LEFT JOIN pilot p ON p.pilot_id = fp.pilot_id
     WHERE fp.montreal_cnt>=2
```

or without a temp table you could do

```
SELECT
       p.pilot_id,
       p.first_name,
       p.last_name
  FROM
       (SELECT
              p.pilot_id,
              f.dep_date,
              -- Find the total number of flights (COUNT) where (CASE WHEN) a flight departs from Montreal (THEN) count it otherwise (ELSE) ignore it (NULL)
              COUNT(CASE WHEN c.city_name = 'MONTREAL' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as 
                montreal_cnt
         FROM flights f
              -- Join in pilot table to get the counts by pilot_id
              LEFT JOIN pilot p ON p.pilot_id = f.pilot_id
              -- Join in city table to get city_name instead of city_id
              LEFT JOIN city c on f.city_dep = c.city_id
        GROUP BY 1, 2) fp
       LEFT JOIN pilot p ON p.pilot_id = fp.pilot_id
-- Only give me the data for pilots who have flown out of Montreal at least twice in one day
 WHERE fp.montreal_cnt>=2
```

Answer (score 0):

For each pilot, you need to count how many flights that pilot has from Montreal, and then retrieve the pilots that have 2 or more flights. This is a job for `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`.

```
SELECT PILOT_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME
FROM PILOT
JOIN FLIGHT USING (PILOT_ID)
JOIN CITY ON (CITY_DEP = CITY_ID)
WHERE CITY_NAME='MONTREAL'
GROUP BY PILOT_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```